# Angular - How does "let" work in the template?

Tags: angular

```
*ngFor="let item of shoppingList;"
```

How does the above template code work?

More specifically, how does `let` work in the template?

This is the code in my component:

```js
@Input()
public set shoppinglist(shoppingList: ShoppingItem[]) {
  this._shoppinglist = shoppingList;
}
public get shoppinglist(): ShoppingItem[] {
  return this._shoppinglist;
}

private _shoppinglist: ShoppingItem[] = [];
```

Why do both `*ngFor="let item of shoppingList;"` and `*ngFor="let item of _shoppingList;"` work?

Comment: Read about the [microsyntax](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax) of Angular Structural Directives.

Answer (score 0):

```js
*ngFor="let item of shoppingList
```

is basically same as array iterating in typescript, it creates a new item from array :

```js
let shoppingList: ShoppingList[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "TEST 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "TEST 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "TEST 3"
  }
];

for (let item of shoppingList) {
  console.log(item);
}

//  OUTPUT
//  { id: 1, name: 'TEST 1' }
//  { id: 2, name: 'TEST 2' }
//  { id: 3, name: 'TEST 3' }
```

Both _shoppingList and shoppingList work the same in your case because you are getting the same thing ( _shoppingList ), the difference is just in shoppingList, which you are getting through getter.